# How to take a function of any number of parameters of any type as a parameter in swift

Tags: swift

This is basically what I am trying to do:

a function that can accept any function with any number of parameters and any return type

Is that even possible?

```
func fun1(x: Int,y: String){

}

func fun2(c: Float){

}

func thefunction(function,parameters) {
    function(parameters[0],parameters[1]...)
}

thefunction(fun1,3,"hi")
thefunction(fun2,4.5)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want `thefunction` to call either `fun1` or `fun2` based on what is passed to `thefunction`?

Answer (score 1):

Swift has the following type for allowing an argument of any type:

```
AnyObject
```

Additionally, you can create one parameter at the end of your parameter list which allows for a dynamic amount of arguments to be passed. I pulled this directly from the Apple documentation for reference:

```
func arithmeticMean(numbers: Double...) -> Double {
    var total: Double = 0
    for number in numbers {
        total += number
    }
    return total / Double(numbers.count)
}
```

You can see the entry [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html). It's amazing what a little bit of research will do..

That said, I don't actually suggest doing this. It makes your code very difficult to understand for other people. If you need to make the function so general that it can literally take any object and return any object in any amount, there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: IIRC, there are some types that can't be represented by `AnyObject` (structs, class objects), but there's an `Any` type that can hold absolutely anything.

Comment: Good addition @NobodyNada in the event that OP truly wants to use absolutely anything it may be necessary to be even **more** general than AnyObject.

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not have an `apply` function. But you can use generic functions:

```
func fun1(x: Int, y: String){
  print(x, y)
}

func fun2(c: Float){
  print(c)
}

func apply<Arg1, Return>(function: (Arg1) -> Return,_ arg: Arg1) ->    Return {
  return function(arg)
}

func apply<Arg1, Arg2, Return>(function: (Arg1, Arg2) -> Return, _ arg1: Arg1, _ arg2: Arg2) -> Return {
  return function(arg1, arg2)
}

apply(fun1, 1, "foo")
apply(fun2, 3.1)
```

The downside is that you need a generic `apply` for each arity.
The upside is that you get a compiler error if you call a function with the wrong parameters.